# Is there a way to hide/disable textfield in ReactJS based on a RadioGroup(FormControlLabel) selection using material ui (mui)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, form-control

[screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Saf.png)
I am working on a project for a hospital webpage using ReactJS and mui and am stuck on the SignUp page..
The Sign up page has a radio option to choose the type of user- Patient or Doctor and then fill out some information.
I am trying to hide/disable certain TextFields (BloodGroup,FamilyDoctor,EmergencyContact) when the Doctor option is chosen and revert back when patient is chosen.

This is how the code looks so far--
I have tried adding handling functions for both the FormControlLabel and Textfield but I don't know how to connect the two. I have added disabled tag to the textfields but I am not able to revert it back using the radio button.

```js
function SignUp(props) {
  //....
  const bloodgroup = document.getElementById("Blood Group");
  const emergencycontact = document.getElementById("Emergencycontact");
  const familydoc = document.getElementById("Family doctor");

  const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
& .Mui-disabled .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline{
disabled:false;
}
`;

  function MyTextField(props) {
    const radioGroup = useRadioGroup();

    let checked = false;

    if (radioGroup) {
      if (radioGroup.value === "Doctor") checked = true;
      else checked = false;
    }

    return <StyledTextField checked={checked} {...props} />;
  }

  const StyledFormControlLabel = styled((props) => (
    <FormControlLabel {...props} />
  ))(({ theme, checked }) => ({
    ".MuiFormControlLabel-label": checked && {
      // Change color here
      color: "red",
    },
  }));

  function MyFormControlLabel(props) {
    // MUI UseRadio Group
    const radioGroup = useRadioGroup();

    let checked = false;

    if (radioGroup) {
      if (radioGroup.value === props.value) checked = true;
      else checked = false;
    }

    return <StyledFormControlLabel checked={checked} {...props} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        <FormLabel id="typeOfLabel">Type Of User</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup row aria-labelledby="typeOfLabel" name="typeofuser">
          <MyFormControlLabel
            value="Patient"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Patient"
          />
          <MyFormControlLabel
            value="Doctor"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Health Care Provider"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <MyTextField
          disabled={true}
          required
          fullWidth
          name="BloodGroup"
          label="BloodGroup"
          type="BloodGroup"
          id="Blood Group"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <TextField
          required
          fullWidth
          name="Contactinfo"
          label="Contactinfo"
          type="email"
          id="Contact info"
          autoComplete="emailaddress"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <MyTextField
          disabled={true}
          required
          fullWidth
          name="Emergencycontact"
          label="Emergencycontact"
          type="email"
          id="Emergencycontact"
          autoComplete="Emergencycontact"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <MyTextField
          disabled={true}
          required
          fullWidth
          name="Familydoctor"
          label="Familydoctor"
          type="email"
          id="Family doctor"
          autoComplete="Familydoctor"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <TextField
          required
          fullWidth
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
          autoComplete="new-password"
        />
      </Grid>
    </>
    //....
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try condition rending for purpose?

Comment: You can render components base on which radio button choice

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @gbatra,

As I understood. You want to display a particular input field. When a specific radio button is selected, for that purpose, You can use condition rendering to achieve that. I make two components, `DoctorField` and `PatientField` and two ***radio*** button `Doctor` and `Patient` and store the value of that radio in the state.
if the state is equal to the patient or doctor. We render the DoctorField or PatientField components based on state value. Here, You could try this. [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-w0ic9p?file=/index.js)